# Custom metrics for jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

My jenkins job "Build" configuration has

- 3 Execute shell - build tasks
- 2 Post build action

Is there any way to get the runtime of each buildtask and postbuild action ?

Comment: isn't it possible to see in jenkins blue ocean view, e.g. on this screenshot https://www.jenkins.io/images/post-images/blueocean-1.5.0/downstream-jobs.png ?

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, which is why:

- I use [a Jenkins plugin timestamper](https://plugins.jenkins.io/timestamper/) to add the timestamps in the logs, giving me the opportunity to extract each task duration.
- there are plugins like [additional-metrics-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/additional-metrics-plugin) or [build-metrics](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-metrics/) which collect job duration (but not necessarily task or post-build task duration): they could be good starting point for making a custom plugin which would collect what you need.